# Can I avoid committing to particular types in a module type and still get pattern matching?

Tags: module, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have two module types:

```
module type ORDERED =
    sig
        type t
        val eq  : t * t -> bool
        val lt  : t * t -> bool
        val leq : t * t -> bool
    end
module type STACK =
    sig
        exception Empty 
        type 'a t
        val empty   : 'a t
        val isEmpty : 'a t -> bool  
        val cons        : 'a * 'a t -> 'a t
        val head        : 'a t -> 'a
        val tail        : 'a t -> 'a t
        val length  : 'a t -> int
    end
```

I want to write a functor which "lifts" the order relation from the basic `ORDERED` type to `STACKs` of that type. That can be done by saying that, for example, two stacks of elements will be equal if all its individual elements are equal. And that stacks s1 and s2 are s.t. s1 < s2 if the first of each of their elements, e1 and e2, are also s.t. e1 < e2, etc.

Now, if don't commit to explicitly defining the type in the module type, I will have to write something like this (or won't I?):

```
module StackLift (O : ORDERED) (S : STACK) : ORDERED =  
  struct
    type t = O.t S.t
    let rec eq (x,y) =
      if S.isEmpty x
        then if S.isEmpty y
        then true
            else false
    else if S.isEmpty y
        then false
        else if O.eq (S.head x,S.head y)
            then eq (S.tail x, S.tail y)
            else false
     (*  etc for lt and leq  *)
  end
```

which is a very clumsy way of doing what pattern matching serves so well. An alternative would be to impose the definition of type `STACK.t` using explicit constructors, but that would tie my *general* module somewhat to a particular implementation, which I don't want to do.

**Question**: can I define something different above so that I can still use pattern matching while at the same time keeping the generality of the module types?

Comment: I agree with axle, your `ORDERED` is a bit weird. One other thing though, if you had `STACK` a functor, then `STACK` itself could have a `eq`,`lt`,.. functions, and can be directly used as an `ORDERED` module; no need for a third module, or a secondary data-type to create a comparison function. As long as a subset of the functions in a module match a module used for a functor, it can be used in that functor.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but rather than three boolean functions, I would rather use a `type order = Lt | Eq | Gt` and `compare : 't -> t -> order`. It's even a good idea to have it internally, as it allows more code factoring that three separate and often redundant lt/eq/gt functions.

Comment: @Gasche, wouldn't implementing `compare : t -> t -> int` be more productive?

Comment: @nlucaroni: would certainly be compatible with most comparison-related standard library functions (such as sorts).

Comment: @gasche Yes, it makes sense to me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative or supplement to the other access functions, the module can provide a view function that returns a variant type to use in pattern matching.

```
type ('a, 's) stack_view = Nil | Cons of 'a * 's

module type STACK =
sig
  val view : 'a t -> ('a , 'a t) stack_view
  ...
end

module StackLift (O : ORDERED) (S : STACK) : ORDERED =
struct
  let rec eq (x, y) =
    match S.view x, S.view y with
        Cons (x, xs), Cons (y, ys) -> O.eq (x, y) && eq (xs, ys)
      | Nil, Nil -> true
      | _ -> false
  ...
end
```

Any stack with a `head` and `tail` function can have a `view` function too, regardless of the underlying data structure.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've answered your own question. A module type in ocaml is an interface which you cannot look behind. Otherwise, there's no point. You cannot keep the generality of the interface while exposing details of the implementation. The only thing you can use is what's been exposed through the interface.

My answer to your question is yes, there might be something you can do to your definition of stack, that would make the type of a stack a little more complex, thereby making it match a different pattern than just a single value, like `(val,val)` for instance. However, you've got a fine definition of a stack to work with, and adding more type-fluff is probably a bad idea.

Some suggestions with regards to your definitions:

1. Rename the following functions: `cons => push`, `head => peek`, `tail => pop_`. I would also add a function `val pop : 'a t -> 'a * 'a t`, in order to combine `head` and `tail` into one function, as well as to mirror `cons`. Your current naming scheme seems to imply that a list is backing your stack, which is a mental leak of the implementation :D.
2. Why do `eq`, `lt`, and `leq` take a pair as the first parameter? In constraining the type of `eq` to be `val eq : 'a t * 'a t -> 'a t`, you're forcing the programmer that uses your interface to keep around one side of the equality predicate until they've got the other side, before finally applying the function. Unless you have a very good reason, I would use the default curried form of the function, since it provides a little more freedom to the user (`val eq : 'a t -> 'a t -> 'a t`). The freedom comes in that they can partially apply `eq` and pass the function around instead of the value and function together.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You said there might be something I could do to make the stack match a different pattern, but you didn't detail it. Did you have anything concrete in mind? I'd like to hear about that. About your suggestions: (1) the signature uses list nomenclature because, following Chris Okasaki, I regard stacks as instances of sequences (which includes queues, for example) and, by having consistent naming conventions for functions across all these abstractions, different implementations can be substituted for each other with a minimum fuss; (2) agreed, point taken, thanks!

Comment: "by having consistent naming conventions for functions across all these abstractions ...". If you want to make sure that the implementation are substituable, you must enforce this by an in-language subtyping constraint. Otherwise your types will easily diverge and you won't notice it. Something like `let () = let module S = (Stack : Sequence) in ()` will silently enforce compatibility.

Comment: @gasche My naming conventions weren't that formal, just to make sure there was some consistency for my own sanity. But this makes sense. Now, is that the best way to do it? It feels really unnatural having to write dummy statements like these so that the compiler checks for inconsistencies.

Comment: @Surikator it is a good way if you want it to be as non-invasive at possible (for example if you added `Sequence` after the fact), which is why I suggested only this way. The more standard way would be to have simply `include Sequence` in the definition of `module type STACK`, instead of the concerned functions (I suppose `cons, nil, head, tail`).